# Solidity - CompilerError: Stack too deep BUT pointing at non-existing variable

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I know similar questions have been asked but this error confuses me because of two unusual things:

1. The contract mentioned is already deployed to Arbitrum so I should be able to deploy it locally
2. There is no variable with this name, neither in the project nor in openzeppelin libraries

So the repository in question is not mine, I want to test it's functionality as I am improving my Solidity knowledge, `CallProxy.sol` in particular: https://github.com/O3Labs/o3swap-v2-core/blob/main/contracts/crossChain/CallProxy.sol

My steps:

1. setup vs code with truffle suite, clone the repository
2. install `@openzeppelin/contracts` through `npm`
3. setup config (I fiddled with the options to try to find a workaround):

   ```
    module.exports = {
        networks: {
            development: {
                network_id: "*",
                port: 8545,
                host: "127.0.0.1"
            }
        },
        mocha: {},
        compilers: {
            solc: {
                version: "0.8.20",
                optimizer: {
                    enabled: true,
                    runs: 20,
                    details: {
                        //optimizerSteps: "u",
                        yui: true
                    }
                },
                viaIR: false
            }
        }
    };
   ```
4. setup migration:

   ```
    const Bridge = artifacts.require("crossChain/Bridge");
    const CallProxy = artifacts.require("crossChain/CallProxy");

    module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
        const gasLimit = 30000000;
        const deployerAddress = accounts[0];
        deployer.deploy(CallProxy, { gas: gasLimit, from: deployerAddress });
        deployer.deploy(Bridge, { gas: gasLimit, from: deployerAddress });
    };
   ```
5. start `ganache`, run `truffle console --network development`
6. `migrate`

Result:

> CompileError: CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables. When compiling inline assembly: Variable headStart is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack. Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables.

Last file reported as `Compiling` in vs code is `https://github.com/O3Labs/o3swap-v2-core/blob/main/contracts/swap/interfaces/IPool.sol` unless this is misleading as well:

[image]

Alternatively:

1. Go to `tenderly`
2. Fork Arbitrum
3. Upload `CallProxy.sol` and all dependencies (you are prompted until they are correct)
4. Click finish:

Result:
[image]

The second attempt, with the cloud, was to make sure it is not the fault of my local setup. I am confused because both of these messages, while essentially the same, are pointing at 2 different variables (1) `headStart` and (2) `ret_0`. None of these exists anywhere in the code or referenced files. The first message is also claiming that the actual problem might be in inline `assembly` declaration but `IPool` (and `Pool`) doesn't even contain inline `assembly`. On top of that all these files are already deployed to L2 Mainnet so I should be able to compile them. I am pretty sure these errors are the outcome of my ignorance but I guess I need to learn somehow. Would be grateful if sb could shed some light on this.